# Change css of visited links with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm working with Wordpress's customizer which allows me to give a live preview of the changes as the user is using it. The following code works for all links, `<a>`, but I want only to change the color of the visited links. Seems like it should be fairly straightforward but I can't seem to achieve it. How can I do this?

```js
  wp.customize('link_visited_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
      $('a')
        .css({
          color: to
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you also add the HTML part of code, so that some solution can be provided by overriding it with CSS styles

Answer (score 0):

You can style a link based on if it was visited using the pseudo class `a:visited` in CSS, but you cannot modify pseudo classes using jQuery because they aren't technically part of the DOM. However, what you can do is append styles to the page using a `<style>` tag. I've modified your code to show you an example of how this can be done.

```js
  wp.customize('link_visited_color', function(value) {
    value.bind(function(to) {
      let styles = `<style>a:visited {color: ${to} !important}</style>`;
      $('#liveStyle').length === 0 ?
        $('head').append(`<div id="liveStyle">${styles}</div>`) :
        $('#liveStyle').html(styles);
   });
  });
```